# Shuffle data in Mongo DB with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, shuffle

I have a Mongo DB database with 1 million entries/rows, which is approx 20 GB of data. I’d like iterate through the data randomly in batches (using python and pymongo), with, say 10 batches of 100K. If I had a small amount of data which I could fit in memory, I would simply load all the data, then shuffle it randomly, then split it into 10 batches. But in this case, I cannot fit it all into memory. So this option is not possible. How could I accomplish this task without being able to fit it into memory?

One idea I had was to add a counter column to my Mongo DB called “count”, which labels each entry as 1,2,3,…, 100K. Then I use a python algo to randomize those numbers. Then I can extract the batches using a simple filter. Does this seem reasonable? It seems pretty slow to be because of all the filters. It seems to not scale efficiently.

This seems like a pretty standard issue. Does someone have a better solution than me?

Comment: Your idea seems similar to [sharding](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/), but you probably need to choose/design a shard key carefully, which the process commonly exceed the content that a single stackoverflow question should hold.

Comment: @ray Is there no simpler solution? This seems like a pretty standard problem in machine learning. I assume many others have faced it.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`"$sample"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/ "Link to MongoDB online reference manual -->").

Comment: @rickhg12hs in that case, i would have N=1mm. Maybe it does work. I will need to give it a try.

Comment: I am not sure whether `$sample` allow you to produce repeatable result by providing seeds. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690714/manually-setting-the-seed-for-mongodb-sample)